# for loop in python; creating a list that holds proportions

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm currently stuck in a rut trying to create a `for` loop.

Here's my objective: I want to create a list holding the proportion of people in each age group for e.g.: the proportion of people in age group 5-10 would be 500/2000 = 0.25

population of people = 2000 
Of which 3 age group exists: "5-10", "11-20", "21-30"
No. of people in each age group respectively: 500, 700, 800

this is what I did:

```
n_pop = 2000
label_list = ['5-10', '11-20', '21-30']
sub_pop = [500, 700, 800]
proportion = []
for i in range(len(sub_pop)):
    proportion = sub_pop[i]/ n_pop
print(proportion)
```

Not sure where I went wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

Just append the values to the list `proportion.append(sub_pop[i]/ n_pop)` instead of assigning them to the list

```
for i in range(len(sub_pop)):
    proportion.append(sub_pop[i]/ n_pop)
```

Comment: one question! samplesize_list = []
for i in range(len(proportion)):
    samplesize_list.append(proportion[i]*obs_size)
print(samplesize_list)

Comment: the list I got are float numbers, how can I make it integer?

Comment: since Im now dealing with no. of people

Comment: @darrenbarren typecast it to `int` while appending : `samplesize_list.append(int(proportion[i]*obs_size)) `

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what your intended outcome is. Since you've declared `proportion` as an empty array, I assume you want to populate it.

You are overwriting the variable `proportion` with every iteration of your loop.

```
for i in range(len(sub_pop)):
    proportion = sub_pop[i]/ n_pop
    print(proportion)
```

The first iteration of the loop, e.g., when `i` is 0, `proportion` is equal to a float, the *first* proportion. Then, when it's 1, you overwrite it and it's then equal to the *second* proportion. The same goes for the third.

As Sruthi, suggested, you need to *add* to this list (as opposed to overwriting your empty list with a brand new value) with `append`. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append

I'd also rename `proportion` to `proportions` if its use is intended to be for storing all of your proportions. Clear variable names can do a lot to help avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good place to try out using a `dictionary`, How about something like this:

```
pop = 2000
age_groups = {'5-10': 500, '11-20': 700, '21-30': 800}
proportion = {}
for k, v in age_groups.items():
    percentage = v/2000
    proportion[k] = int(percentage * 100)

print(proportion, '\n')

for i in proportion:
    print(f"Age group {i} is {proportion[i]}% of Population {pop}")
```

I included two `print` methods to give you some ideas what you could do with this

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 loop_pop.py 
> {'5-10': 25, '11-20': 35, '21-30': 40} 
>
> Age group 5-10 is 25% of Population 2000
> Age group 11-20 is 35% of Population 2000
> Age group 21-30 is 40% of Population 2000
> ```